# Calculating the correct width to resize image to display in a CListCtrl

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, clistctrl

At the moment I am having to fudge my code like this:

```
CRect rcList;
m_ListThumbnail.GetClientRect(rcList);
rcList.DeflateRect(25, 25);

// Use monitor 1 to work out the thumbnail sizes
CRect rcMonitor = m_monitors.rcMonitors.at(0);

m_iThumbnailWidth = rcList.Width();

double dHt = ((double)rcMonitor.Height() / (double)rcMonitor.Width()) * (double)m_iThumbnailWidth;
m_iThumbnailHeight = (int)dHt;
```

I fudge it by deflating the rectangle by 25. `m_ListThumbnail` is a `CListCtrl` and I am trying to render my thumbnails so that I do not need a horizontal scroll bar.

When I render the thumbnails of the monitors, I attempt to massage these thumbnail values (incomplete):

```
nWidth = m_iThumbnailWidth;

double dHt = ((double)rcCapture.Height() / (double)rcCapture.Width()) * (double)m_iThumbnailWidth;
nHeight = (int)dHt;

if (nHeight > m_iThumbnailHeight)
{
    AfxMessageBox(L"Need to investigate!");
}
```

Where `rcCapture` is the size of the monitor.

If I remove the `DeflateRect` line, my window displays like this:

[image]

As you can see, it is note as I expected. There is a horizontal scroll bar and I have to resize quite a bit to see the thumbnail:

[image]

All I want to compute is a set of thumbnail dimensions so that the scaled down monitor image is going to fit in the `CListCtrl`. I don't really want the user to have to resize the window.

---

### Update

With my adjusted code which now uses the primary monitor aspect ratio to work out the thumbnail sizes (as added above) renders the app with better whitespace:

[image]

That was the reason of the extra space at the bottom because the monitors were 16:9 and I was squishing into 4:3. So that is fixed.

But as you can see, using the `CListCtrl` client width is not sufficient.

---

### Update

This is the rendering code:

```
// Set the mode first!
SetStretchBltMode(dcImage, COLORONCOLOR);

int iTop = (m_iThumbnailHeight - nHeight) / 2;

// Copy (and resize)
bRet = ::StretchBlt(dcImage, 0, iTop,
    nWidth, 
    nHeight, 
    dcScreen.m_hDC, 
    rcCapture.left, 
    rcCapture.top, 
    rcCapture.Width(), 
    rcCapture.Height(), SRCCOPY | CAPTUREBLT);
```

Comment: Is the issue that the `rcCapture.Width()` is different from the width of your source bitmap? If so, that could be caused by DPI awareness issues, if you don't have  DPI-awareness set in your application's manifest. This issue can maybe happen if your monitor(s) is(are) set to a non "100%" scaling. (Just guessing, though.)

Comment: @AdrianMole I have changed my code a little. But to answer your question, the issue is that when I get the width of the control and use it to resize the image down, that it does not fit in the control without scrolling. In other words, give a CListCtrl, what is the actual available "width" we can render into without causing a horz scroll? I used 25 pixels.

Comment: There's a lot of white space around the thumbnail. It appears that your rendering code (not shown) adds some margins around the bitmap, but you don't account for them in your computations.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik See updated question. That was because of the forcing 16:9 into 4:3 and thus having a band at the bottom. That is now fixed. But it does now answer the  `CListCtrl` width matter.

Comment: Again - the thumbnail is not rendered flush to the edge of the control; there's some space between the edge of the control, and the edge of the thumbnail. I can only assume that your rendering code draws the bitmap so that its top left corner is at some coordinate `x` relative to the client area of the control, where `x>0`. But when you compute the width of the thumbnail, you don't leave any space for these margins - you assume that the thumbnail would eventually be rendered at `x==0`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik No, I don't. I have updated the question with the rendering code. I move down the Y (true) but that code is obsolete now. The x is left at 0. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have found out that when I use `m_ListThumbnail.GetItemPosition(monitorIndex, &pt);` the x value is 21. So the system is adding 21 pixels to the image size. I can set the position as 0 but under the hood it still uses 21 pixels.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thats why my deflate works because it takes that into account. But why 21 pix? How the CListCtrl decide that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control renders the icon with a **margin**. When I used `GetItemPosition` function it indicated that the `x` value was 21. This is why my `DeflateRect(25, 25)` worked. But I don;t know how the `CListCtrl` computed that margin value.

---

Eventually I found out how to do this without deflating, by using the  [`SetIconSpacing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/clistctrl-class?view=msvc-170#seticonspacing) function. Like this:

```
m_ListThumbnail.SetIconSpacing(
    CSize(m_iThumbnailWidth, ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXHSCROLL)));
```

Once the above has been done the window looks like this:

[image]

Things might be a little different when there are 3 or 4 monitor thumbnails, thus causing a vertical scroll bar. But I only have two monitors to test with.